# Jenknis. После успешного выполнения теста, выключает агента на виртуальной машине и отмечает тест как FILED

Tags: java, jenkins

Запускаю через `Jenkins` тест на виртуальной машине. Он проходит успешно, но на моменте записи результатов об окончании теста возникает ошибка:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 42:45 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-23T12:02:27+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 41M/391M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[...]

C:\jenkinsWorkspace\workspace\44_autotrade_test_servicing>exit 0 
FATAL: java.io.IOException: Connection aborted: org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$MonoNioTransport@465e46e8[name=SlaveAgent1]
hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.io.IOException: Connection aborted: org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$MonoNioTransport@465e46e8[name=SlaveAgent1]
    at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:303)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:847)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$1.terminate(Channel.java:509)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractByteArrayCommandTransport$1.terminate(AbstractByteArrayCommandTransport.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$NioTransport.abort(NioChannelHub.java:208)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub.run(NioChannelHub.java:629)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at ......remote call to SlaveAgent1(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
    at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:172)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:780)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher.kill(Launcher.java:953)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:540)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection aborted: org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$MonoNioTransport@465e46e8[name=SlaveAgent1]
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$NioTransport.abort(NioChannelHub.java:208)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub.run(NioChannelHub.java:629)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.FifoBuffer$Pointer.receive(FifoBuffer.java:137)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.FifoBuffer.receive(FifoBuffer.java:310)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub.run(NioChannelHub.java:561)
    ... 6 more
```

После этого в `Jenkins'е` тест отмечается как непройденный и при этом на виртуальной машине выключается агент, и для его поднятия необходимо заходить на машину и включать заново, делается это так:

1. Открытие командной строки от имени Администратора
2. Вводится
   команда `java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl
   http://адрес_мастера:8080/computer/имя_агента/slave-agent.jnlp`

Запускать как службу возможности нет.

Версия `Jenkins` ver. 2.7.1, `Java` - 8.

Какие есть варианты решения проблемы, чтобы агент не выключался?

---

Мне посоветовали перенаправить вывод с консоли в файл, результаты следующие:
https://pastebin.com/UpwzsFUb

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88757/discussion-on-question-by-rob-jenknis-----).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(15);` в метод с аннотацией `@After` (выполняется всегда после теста независимо от результата завершения)